# How can I make a hotkey to play/pause music?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, autohotkey, hotkeys

I used to have a laptop that had a function hotkey to play/pause music when you had a music player (iTunes, mediamonkey). I have a new laptop now, but it doesn't have that hotkey anymore. How can I create a hotkey to play/pause music? (I have a windows 8.1 laptop by the way)

Comment: Many players themselves allow you to configure global hotkeys. You could use one of those.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download ZIP (no installer) version of [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/releases/view/79616).
2. Map an unused key (<kbd>F12</kbd> for example) to the <kbd>Play/Pause</kbd> Media key and update the registry as follows:

   [image: 1]

   [image: 2]
3. Log off and log back on or reboot. You can optionally also delete the program now if you don't require it any longer.